# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' - Something escapes my logic

Tags: python, numpy, append

I'm trying to run a decision tree algorithm on a set of data based on the method used [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-supply-chain-forecast-66ef297f58f2).

I have cleaned the data and everything is ok based on the example from medium.

I'm trying to define the function:

```
def datasets  (df, x_len = 12, y_len = 1, y_test_len = 12):
D = df.values
periods = D.shape[1]

#Training Dataset Creation

loops = periods + 1 - x_len - y_len - y_test_len
train = []
for col in range(loops):
    train.append(D[:,col:col+x_len+y_len])
    train = np.vstack(train)
    X_train, Y_train = np.split(train, [x_len], axis = 1)
    

#Test set creation

max_col_test = periods - x_len - y_len + 1
test = []
for col in range(loops, max_col_test):
    test.append(D[:,col:col+x_len+ y_len])
    test = np.vstack(test)
    X_test, Y_test = np.split(test, [x_len], axis = 1)
```

The training Data set creation works just fine, but in the Test set creation piece of code i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't get it what it happens, since in the first loop it works just fine so something is clearly escaping my logic.

Comment: `train` produced by `vstack` is an array, no longer a list.

Comment: Hello @hpaulj, but in the the test set creation i'm not using the train anymore. The error i get is about this one: line 43, in datasets
    test.append(D[:,col:col+x_len+ y_len])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in range(loops):
    train.append(D[:,col:col+x_len+y_len])
    train = np.vstack(train)
    X_train, Y_train = np.split(train, [x_len], axis = 1)
```

the error is in the code above.

After `train = np.vstack(train)`, `train` becomes a numpy array, not a list, so in the next iteration you are going to append a value on a numpy array which doesn't have an `append` method, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you insight. Do you see a quick fix for this one. Is there a way to do a workaround that or it's an issue with the whole underlying logic of the code?

Comment: it appears to me you want to get all X examples and then split them into train and test right ? and the same thing for target values .

if that's the case , then you can know the part of (array D)  which you want to take , instead of doing it in for loop , that way you reduce complexity , and also you should be able to solve the problem .

Comment: Thanks a lot Husam for your insight. I'll proceed with a more general approach of the algorithm.